# Can OpenMAX for Android NDK be used for streaming live video/audio to a server? Example?

Tags: android, android-ndk, video-streaming, video-capture, openmax

OpenMax has a concept called "Data Sink".

Specification says about them:

```
Its data locator which identifies where the data resides. Possible locators include:
• URIs (such as a filename)
• Memory addresses
• I/O devices
• Output Mixes
• Cameras
```

Here is some sample code from specification:

```
/* Setup the data sink structure */
uri.locatorType = XA_DATALOCATOR_URI;
uri.URI = (XAchar *) "file:///recordsample.wav";
audioSink.pLocator = (void*) &uri;
```

Some other places, however, it says:

```
URIs pointing to audio files in the local file system
```

Does anyone know whether OpenMax with these URI's / data sinks can be used to implement a **streaming app that captures live data from mic/camera and streams it to server?** Example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "NO". The NDK [document](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/docs/openmaxal/index.html) explicitly says that the Androoid implementation of OpneMAX AL does not, as of today, expose any features beyond that of the Java [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).